# Selenium with IE 11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am looking forward to get below help .

I was doing Test Automation for an application in Chrome with Xpaths . It was working well. But now I have a requirement to use the same suite to do cross browser testing in IE 11 .

Currently Using 2.39 IE Webdriver for Selenium . I am able to open browser but with my X path with which had my script ,not working with X path in IE 11 .

So here is my Question

1. Will I be able to use the Xpath used for chrome to do automation in IE 11
2. Also I found Execution is slower in IE 11 when compared to chrome
3. Do we have any X path Checker in IE 11 similarly in Chrome,Firefox .My requirement is to check all the x paths i used for chrome works in IE or not.But i dont know how should i check .
4. I understand from all the forums to go with CSS instead of X path , I can also do the same but just to understand is the X path same across Chrome and IE 11
5. Last i would like to understand a basic thing, when we say Xpath native support not present in ie browser -what do we mean

PS : I used Capabilities Ignorezoomsetting to true,require window focus to true ,native elements to false for Internet Explorer

Thanks in Advance

Html Code :

```
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>-</title>
<style data-styled-components=""></style></head>

<body>
  <div id="modal"></div>
  <div id="app"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw ixXCQP" overflow="auto" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="NavBarIndicator__NavBarIndicatorHtml-ibzzfP jRSwXJ"><div class="NavBarIndicator__Indicator-eUunBf jITNXW"></div><div class="NavBarIndicator__IndicatorSettings-kgrEUt cPoXyp"></div></div><div class="Header__HeaderWrapper-cPhxZP hLpJId"><img class="_NavBarMenu__MenuIcon-gZnMef eTeQZD" src="/assets/images/menu.png"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw eaWcQg" width="100%" height="100%" display="flex"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw iuKZOD" width="200px" display="flex"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw cHydLU" cursor="pointer" width="0 auto" display="flex"><a href="new-client" style="text-decoration: none;"><a class="AnchorLink__LinkWrapper-kpcMPo iKDWLW" color="#696969" font-size="14px" font-family="OpenSans">New Client</a></a></div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw cHydLU" cursor="pointer" width="0 auto" display="flex"><a class="AnchorLink__LinkWrapper-kpcMPo cJfTFc" color="#696969" font-size="14px" font-family="OpenSans">Existing Client</a></div></div></div></div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw eXWVrO" width="100%" display="flex"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__AccordionContainer-lhzlfC jUObfx" name="basicDetailsAccordion" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__ActiveBar-fUxxNn dIFKrP" width="100%"></div><div class="Accordion__TopBarContainer-eqOfxK dbwwMy"><div class="Accordion__HeaderText-btWcFX kpnLnx">BASICS</div><div class="Accordion__ArrowContainer-jgNnsk joAlIe"></div></div><div class="Accordion__ContentContainer-bNGADI dUFUSp"><div class="Grid__Row-eThVWD keRYro"><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="Dropdown__DropdownContainer-iuXXkE eGcMOz" value=""><input class="Dropdown__InputField-XdsGe saBoZ" placeholder="" value=""><div class="Dropdown__FloatingLabel-dAuMht kobteq" value="">Title</div><div class="Dropdown__baseIconStyle-hZrHDI dGulpi" value=""></div><div class="Dropdown__DescOrErrorContainer-CVXZE cVVTfy"></div><div class="Dropdown__DropdownItemsContainer-ePnZKJ jIlnqS"></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="TextField__Wrapper-iMDdAX jeqFJ" value=""><input class="TextField__Input-eZJwmJ hjrRW" type="text" value=""><div class="TextField__Label-hiPeUU dbpoGq" value="">Christian Name</div><span class="TextField__Text-jWKysX jCdXZa"></span><div></div></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Row-eThVWD keRYro"><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="TextField__Wrapper-iMDdAX jeqFJ" value=""><input class="TextField__Input-eZJwmJ hjrRW" type="text" value=""><div class="TextField__Label-hiPeUU dbpoGq" value="">Given Name</div><span class="TextField__Text-jWKysX jCdXZa"></span><div></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="TextField__Wrapper-iMDdAX jeqFJ" value=""><input class="TextField__Input-eZJwmJ hjrRW" type="text" value=""><div class="TextField__Label-hiPeUU dbpoGq" value="">Surname *</div><span class="TextField__Text-jWKysX jCdXZa"></span><div></div></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Row-eThVWD keRYro"><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="Dropdown__DropdownContainer-iuXXkE eGcMOz" value=""><input class="Dropdown__InputField-XdsGe saBoZ" placeholder="" value=""><div class="Dropdown__FloatingLabel-dAuMht kobteq" value="">Marital Status</div><div class="Dropdown__baseIconStyle-hZrHDI dGulpi" value=""></div><div class="Dropdown__DescOrErrorContainer-CVXZE cVVTfy"></div><div class="Dropdown__DropdownItemsContainer-ePnZKJ jIlnqS"></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="TextField__Wrapper-iMDdAX jeqFJ" value=""><input class="TextField__Input-eZJwmJ hjrRW" type="date" value=""><div class="TextField__Label-hiPeUU dbpoGq" value=""></div><span class="TextField__Text-jWKysX jCdXZa"></span><div></div></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Row-eThVWD keRYro"><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="Dropdown__DropdownContainer-iuXXkE eGcMOz" value=""><input class="Dropdown__InputField-XdsGe saBoZ" placeholder="" value=""><div class="Dropdown__FloatingLabel-dAuMht kobteq" value="">Nationality</div><div class="Dropdown__baseIconStyle-hZrHDI dGulpi" value=""></div><div class="Dropdown__DescOrErrorContainer-CVXZE cVVTfy"></div><div class="Dropdown__DropdownItemsContainer-ePnZKJ jIlnqS"></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="TextField__Wrapper-iMDdAX jeqFJ" value=""><input class="TextField__Input-eZJwmJ hjrRW" type="text" value=""><div class="TextField__Label-hiPeUU dbpoGq" value="">NRIC or Passport number</div><span class="TextField__Text-jWKysX jCdXZa"></span><div></div></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Row-eThVWD keRYro"><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw hhPbtN" height="80px" value="maleRadio" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Radio__Header-iLHfxq epdwGX">Gender</div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Radio__Child-iQExMs iJGsOb" value="maleRadio">Male</div><div class="Radio__Child-iQExMs gETYuF" value="femaleRadio">Female</div></div></div></div><div class="Grid__Column-dzIFTK cYStlC"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw hhPbtN" height="80px" value="smokerYesRadio" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Radio__Header-iLHfxq epdwGX">Smoker</div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Radio__Child-iQExMs iJGsOb" value="smokerYesRadio">Yes</div><div class="Radio__Child-iQExMs gETYuF" value="smokerNoRadio">No</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__AccordionContainer-lhzlfC iOrkBi" name="contactDetailsAccordion" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__ActiveBar-fUxxNn dRpCWJ" width="100%"></div><div class="Accordion__TopBarContainer-eqOfxK dbwwMy"><div class="Accordion__HeaderText-btWcFX kpnLnx">CONTACT</div><div class="Accordion__ArrowContainer-jgNnsk cmIaNs"></div></div></div></div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__AccordionContainer-lhzlfC iOrkBi" name="educationDetailsAccordion" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__ActiveBar-fUxxNn dRpCWJ" width="100%"></div><div class="Accordion__TopBarContainer-eqOfxK dbwwMy"><div class="Accordion__HeaderText-btWcFX kpnLnx">EDUCATION &amp; OCCUPATION</div><div class="Accordion__ArrowContainer-jgNnsk cmIaNs"></div></div></div></div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__AccordionContainer-lhzlfC iOrkBi" name="othersAccordion" width="100%"><div class="Accordion__ActiveBar-fUxxNn dRpCWJ" width="100%"></div><div class="Accordion__TopBarContainer-eqOfxK dbwwMy"><div class="Accordion__HeaderText-btWcFX kpnLnx">OTHERS</div><div class="Accordion__ArrowContainer-jgNnsk cmIaNs"></div></div></div></div><div class="Flex-kFpfAw kgPlre" display="flex" width="100%"><div class="Flex-kFpfAw iJaRwj" width="100%" display="flex"><a href="/client"><input class="Button__ButtonHtml-kIBguK eybnQU" type="submit" value="Back"></a><div class="Space-fYzrqg kpkBkk"></div><input class="Button__ButtonHtml-kIBguK kkGQYo" type="submit" value="Next"></div></div></div><div class="Overlay__OverlayHtml-fHbRtE iMIwlR"></div><div class="NavBarIndicator__NavBarIndicatorHtml-ibzzfP jRSwXJ"><div class="NavBarIndicator__Indicator-eUunBf jITNXW"></div><div class="NavBarIndicator__IndicatorSettings-kgrEUt cPoXyp"></div></div><div class="NavBar__NavBarHtml-AmdPv dLHKZS" color="red"><div class="NavBar__CloseButton-bbtqJM jXPpvT"><img class="NavBar__CloseIcon-kbJaLK hqvvWp" src="/assets/images/leftArrow.png"></div><a id="new-proposal" href="/client" style="text-decoration: none;"><div class="_NavBarButton__NavBarButtonHtml-jFBQvK hjgrnZ"><img class="_NavBarButton__NavBarIcon-koVGUP gjfdcG" src="/assets/images/addActive.png"><br><div class="_NavBarButton__Label-deFDME llMpjg">New Proposal</div></div></a><a href="/transactions" style="text-decoration: none;"><div class="_NavBarButton__NavBarButtonHtml-jFBQvK hjgrnZ"><img class="_NavBarButton__NavBarIcon-koVGUP gjfdcG" src="/assets/images/transaction.png"><br><div class="_NavBarButton__Label-deFDME ofuLs">Transactions</div></div></a><a href="/opportunity" style="text-decoration: none;"><div class="_NavBarButton__NavBarButtonHtml-jFBQvK hjgrnZ"><img class="_NavBarButton__NavBarIcon-koVGUP gjfdcG" src="/assets/images/opportunity.png"><br><div class="_NavBarButton__Label-deFDME ofuLs">Opportunity</div></div></a><a href="/settings" style="text-decoration: none;"><div class="NavBar__SettingsButton-gpFICj jHbjOK"><img class="NavBar__NavBarIcon-blvkXP fBFcQi" src="/assets/images/setting.png"><br><div class="NavBar__Label-eCmPLc cIziCb">Settings</div></div></a></div></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/vendors~main.50b6700db1e18bf97471.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/main.50b6700db1e18bf97471.js"></script>



<!-- version: PROD  --></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Will I be able to use the Xpath used for chrome to do automation in IE 11 :

The answer is **No**. use **cssSelector** , sometimes the **xpath** may work if it is not too much absolute. May be relative would do the job much easier.

2. Also I found Execution is slower in IE 11 when compared to chrome

There is no native support for **xpath** in **IE**, use again **cssSelector** to overcome this issue.

3. I understand from all the forums to go with **CSS** instead of X path , I can also do the same but just to understand is the X path same across Chrome and IE 11 .

   - No it is not same , again go with **cssSelector**
4. Last i would like to understand a basic thing, when we say Xpath native support not present in ie browser -what do we mean

It means that IE engine does not have anything for xpath , IE has to use 3rd party to get along with xpath.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Expert:) Got to understand from you i cant use Xpath .But in mean time i tried with CSS .What happens is ,I have a text box which was working fine with Xpath in Chrome . But in IE when i tried with css it sets the value but when moved to other element set value gets disappeared . Tried with Thread.sleep,WebDriver wait Untill element existence,First click and later send keys ,Action class ,Java script executor all but same behavior im seeing .(setting the value but when focus moved out value disappears) . But when manually set its setting value permanently .

Comment: PS: i want to try if this is same for other Text Fields as well . But Unfortunately yes for all text fields . I want to understand is it problem with my code or Locator or IE driver (I use 2.39 IE driver) or Application development (This is React Application) .But funniest part is it works all properly without hiccups in Chrome . Only in IE i face all these issues

Comment: Does it mean i should only or can go only with Setting ID asking developer to keep id and can access elements only with ID :(

Comment: No you should not ask developer for any kind of changes. You have to use id, classname , tagname , linkText , partialLinkText, then css and then xpath.

Comment: Thanks for replying promptly .but the application what s developed now does not have unique id for the elements . It’s dynamically generated . Please help me in such case how can I go about with.

Comment: Could you plese share the html code? You can edit the question and update it with html code, Thanks !

Comment: The problem you are facing right now may be because of IE driver , and browser version.

Comment: I have updated Html code for one of the element .For the same element i tried setting text in all possible ways but in chrome it works but in ie , value on UI getting set, but later when i print get text or get attribute of value prints empty . also as soon i move to other element value disappears .

Comment: Please help me knowing which version of driver i need to use for ie 11 . Possibly if you can help me sending link i can give a try with it and let you know .

Comment: @AadityaSeshadri : not in that way , right click on the web page click on inspect and then under element section , you would see the html , share that html.

Comment: Sure I will be sharing the links in some times. Just give me some time for that.

Comment: thanks i have copied the html of the page . Please have look .Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok I will look into this matter , and update you as soon as I get anything.

Comment: Thanks :) waiting for valuable solution

Comment: Can you please let me know the compatible IE Webdriver for IE 11 so that i doubt i use wrong version . If version changed might work all well.

Comment: I have found a useful link : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: @AadityaSeshadri : anytime brother.